# Python - Hours between two dates, excluding weekends

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing my first steps in python programing language. I want to create a script that aims to open an excel file and add an extra column that will be the hourly difference between the two dates and save it to another file. To count hours I'm using businessDuration from https://pypi.org/project/business-duration/

My DF looks like that:

```
Id | Date1               | Date2               | Date3
1    01/01/2022 08:10:51 | 02/01/2022 08:15:51 | 15/01/2022 23:15:51
2    01/01/2022 08:15:51 (and so on) for every column with dates
3
4
```

My code look's like that

```
    import pandas as pd
    import os
    import warnings
    from datetime import time, datetime
    from business_duration import businessDuration
    from itertools import repeat
    
    def WeekDays_hour(start, end, un):
        start_date = start
        end_date = end
        unit = un
        return list(map(businessDuration, start_date, end_date, repeat(unit)))

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\M\\PycharmProjects\\Python\\source")
car_path = os.getcwd()
for filename in os.listdir(car_path):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True):
            warnings.simplefilter("always")
            df = pd.read_excel(car_path+'\\'+filename, engine="openpyxl")
        if df['Date1'] is not None:
                df['Time difference'] = WeekDays_hour(df['Date1'], df['Date2'], 'hour')
df.to_excel("C:\\Users\\M\\PycharmProjects\\Python\\rep\\"+filename, index=False)
```

I want to be able to call function "WeekDays_hour" for every pair of dates I need and as of result of this function I want to have another column in df.

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, program is finishing without errors, but added column is empty. No calculations done. If any of you have any ideas I will be grateful.

EDIT:
I tried @BeRT2me code.

When i put it like that:

```
from business_duration import businessDuration
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\M\PycharmProjects\CAR\test.xlsx')

def weekdays_hour(x: pd.Series, start_date: str, end_date: str, un: str) -> int:
    if x[start_date] and x[end_date]:
        return businessDuration(x[start_date], x[end_date], un)

df['difference'] = df.apply(weekdays_hour, args=('Date1', 'Date2', 'hour'))

df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\M\PycharmProjects\redy\Closed.xlsx", index=False)
```

When I run it I received error "KeyError: 'Date1'"

when I changed

```
df['difference'] = df.apply(weekdays_hour, axis=1, args=('Date1', 'Date2', 'hour'))
```

code run without errors, column was added but it was empty.

ANSWER by BeRT2me:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x['input'], x['input2']), axis=1)
```

and it works like a charm.

EDIT some time later:

df.applay was a little slow for me and I managed to find a quicker method:

```
def workdays(a, b, unit):
    return pd.Series([businessDuration(Date1, Date2, unit=unit) for (Date1, Date2) in zip(df[a], df[b])])
```

a, b = column names (like 'Date1')
unit = 'hour', 'day'

Comment: I assume when you print df you can't see the column too right? The first thing that came to me was that maybe your pathing is wrong.

Comment: Also, a random tidbit, but `r"C:\Users\M\PycharmProjects\Python\source"` is the same as `"C:\\Users\\M\\PycharmProjects\\Python\\source"` and can lead to a lot less headache with `\\` everywhere...

Comment: @Batselot new column is present in file, just empty

Comment: @BeRT2me thanks for this info, it will be much easier :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dug deeper into the code of businessDuration and found that the following is already explicitly defined, so neither `if df['Date1'] is not None:` nor `if x[start_date] and x[end_date]:` are needed.

```
if pd.isnull(startdate) or pd.isnull(enddate) or startdate>enddate:
        return np.nan
```

It also appears that `unit` must be a named input, or it returns `np.nan`.

Also, keep in mind that in your test data, Data1 > Date2, so it'll return `np.nan`. If those are given as startdate, enddate respectively.

Given this, the following should work just fine:

```
df['difference'] = df.apply(lambda x: businessDuration(x['Date2'], x['Date1'], unit='hour'), axis=1)
```

My Output:

```
                Date1               Date2               Date3   difference
0 2022-04-13 08:10:51 2022-02-01 08:15:51 2022-01-15 23:15:51  1223.916667
```

No need for any of my custom code, unless you want to rewrite how `buisinessDuration` takes inputs~

Comment: Look neat, could you explain it a little for educational purpose? I need to pass 2 dates to function and specify what interval I need (alter between 'hour' and 'day'). In you proposition i see that 'Date1' and 'Date2' is hardcoded in function?

Comment: @Tsura I realized I massively overcomplicated things. I've modified the code to where you can pick which columns to use for `start_date`, and `end_date`, along with the `unit` you'd like returned. I tried to comment everything so you can understand what's going on~

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks. One question tho, should "start_date = 'Date1'" have some reference to dataframe? like df['Date1']? Second one - can it be wrapped in "def xxx: ... return "df.apply(....". I will have to perform this function at least 10 times in one file, for 10 different columns.

Comment: No, `start_date = 'Date1'` is a string that's later passed to `x[start_date]` which is equivalent to `x['Date1']` in this case~ I've added a function/methodology that should be easier to use for repeatability.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and willingness to continue helping me, but it looks like I'm lost again. Can you read my revision in the original post and try to help me?

Comment: @Tsura TLDR; I dug deeper, found a better answer.  Here's how you properly apply a function to make a new column using specific columns as input variables... `df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x['input'], x['input2']), axis=1)`